# Can a business operate in one state ie. NY and have an office in another?

Tags: united-states, small-business, irs

My prospective business is going to operate in NYC but due to unforeseen consequences my "office" or base of operation will be in another state. What sort of consequences or altercations can I experiences due to this circumstance (IRS)?